# How to get once instance of service with Inject

Tags: angular, angular2-services

**How can I get the same once instance of singleton service using Injector:**

I define provider of this service on the bootstrap application(for one instance on the all application)

**Example:**

### Bootstrap application

```
//Init application
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS, SessionService]);
```

### SessionService

Singleton - this is just example, but in real can be session or acl service

```
@Injectable()
export class SessionService {
    constructor() {
        console.warn("INSTANCE OF SESSION SERVICE-a");
    }
    public getInstance(instanceName: string){
        console.warn("Injected service come from component name: " + instanceName);
    }
}
```

### SecuredHomeComponent

When I inject service on the constructor has only once instance of services **(good)**

```
@Component()
@CanActivate(AccessService.checkSession)
export class SecuredHomeComponent {
    public constructor(private testSessionService: SessionService) {
        this.testSessionService.getInstance('Component1:1'); //Test 1 - get the same instance when service is inject into contructor
    }
}
```

### MyStaticService

I try like this, inject service but All the time get new Instance of service
But I need inject directly into for example static method using "Injector.resolveAndCreate" then NG2 create new Instance of service **(bad)**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyStaticService {
    public static getDataFromService() {
        //That two ways is bad, bcs create new instance of my test SessionService
        //Test4
        let providers = Injector.resolve([ SessionService ]);
        let injectorFirst = Injector.fromResolvedProviders(providers);
        let testServFirst = injectorFirst.get(SessionService);
        testServFirst.getInstance('StaticService1:1');
        //Test 5
        let injectorSecond = Injector.resolveAndCreate([SessionService]);
        let testServSecond = injectorSecond.get(SessionService);
        testServSecond.getInstance('StaticService1:2');
    }
}
```

### Static Service

For real example, I need static class with static method
If I good understand doc, when want overwrites methods for annotation **canActivate** must provide servise with static method

Line: @CanActivate(AccessService.checkSession) in my "SecuredHomeComponent"

```
//Static Service - ACCESS
@Injectable()
export class AccessService {
    public static checkAccess = (next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction): boolean => {        
        return AccessService.checkSession() && AccessService.checkAcl(res, priv);
    }
    public static checkSession(): boolean {
        let injectedSessionServices: SessionService; //How to inject the same instance of my SessionService?
        return injectedSessionServices.getDataFromService(); //for real service he get back checkSession from sessionService
    }
    public static checkAcl(aclResource: AclResources, aclPrivilege: AclPrivileges): boolean {
        let injectedAclServices: SessionService; //How to inject the same instance of my SessionService?
        return injectedAclServices.checkAcl(aclResource, aclPrivilege);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why this needs to be a static method? The code in the static method doesn't make much sense. `new CommonTestService()` does the same and you save about 10 lines of code.

Comment: I update code, for real example what for i need use static class with static method - need overvrite method of annotation **@CanActivate**

Comment: Hete is discussed how to use `CanActivate` with DI https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112#issuecomment-139381970 (with Plunker)

Comment: I read discussed about "CanActivate" but I still don't find solution for me. I resolve my implementation "canActivate" with use extend Service and I thing this is good solution, and work me very nice. I can implement my static class with singletion implementation using **getInstance** of my service but what for if NG2 have own implementation od one instance of service using Inect mechanism? I want use him. And other thing is I want now how can I inject some instance of service into the body of my method of class without constructor, is this is posible?

Comment: **See [this article](https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/authentication-in-angular-2-958052c64492#.yatiajvjh)'s `appInjector` function**, which you **bootstrap** and **store a reference of `injector`**, then **just call this function** to get **instance of any `service`.**

Comment: I am write about this on my last answer of this post - I thing this is the same what you write. By the way, I see in RC realse NG2 they make CanActivate _(Remove canActivate; Add canActiveteChild)_ decorator injectable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution with using one instance of global service **injector** implemented standard singleton class with **getInstance()** into bootstrap application. And after that can get simple instance of injected service on all level of application. If some time somebody find different solution, or NG2 resolve this different pls let me know.

**Sample code for very simple example:**

Bootstrap app

```
//Init application
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, MY_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS])
    .then((appRef) => MainInjectorService.getInstance().setInjector(appRef.injector));
```

My helpers main injector

```
import { Injector, Injectable } from 'angular2/src/core/di';

@Injectable()
export class MainInjectorService
{
    static instance:MainInjectorService;    
    static isCreating:Boolean = false;
    private _injector: Injector;

    constructor() {
        if (!MainInjectorService.isCreating) {
            throw new Error("You can't call new in Singleton instances!");
        }
    }

    public static getInstance() {
        if (MainInjectorService.instance == null) {
            MainInjectorService.isCreating = true;
            MainInjectorService.instance = new MainInjectorService();
            MainInjectorService.isCreating = false;
        }

        return MainInjectorService.instance;
    }

    public setInjector(injector: Injector) {
        this._injector = injector;
    }

    public getInjector(): Injector {
        return this._injector;
    }
}
```

My STATIC class

```
// Access - static service 
@Injectable()
export class StaticAccessService {

    // Get service instance from global provides service
    private static _getService<T>(serviceName: any) {
        let injector: Injector = MainInjectorService.getInstance().getInjector();
        return injector.get(serviceName);
    }

    //Check access to session and acl
    public static checkAccess = (next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction): boolean => {
        return StaticAccessService.checkSession() && StaticAccessService.checkAcl(next.routeData.data['res'], next.routeData.data['priv']);
    }

    // Check session access
    public static checkSession(): boolean {
        return StaticAccessService._getService(MySessionService).checkSession();
    }

    // Check session access
    public static checkAccess(res, priv): boolean {
        return StaticAccessService._getService(MyAclService).checkAccess(res, priv);
    }
}
```

And how to use in component

```
@Component()
@CanActivate(StaticAccessService.checkAccess)
export class SecuredComponent {
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code that demonstrates your solution? Where does `getInstance()` come from and what does it do?

Answer (score 2):

Angulars DI keeps one instance per provider. If an instance is requested from the same provider, the same instance is returned every time.

What you can do is, to provide a factory and call the factory to get a new instance.

```ts
bootstrap(AppComponent, [provide(CommonTestService, {useFactory: () => {
  return () => {
    new CommonTestService();
  }
})]);
```

if the service itself has dependencies (constructor parameters) then you need to provide them as well

```ts
bootstrap(AppComponent, [MyServiceDependency, provide(CommonTestService, {useFactory: () => {
  return () => {
    new CommonTestService(dep);
  },
  deps: [MyServiceDependency]
})]);
```

Then you can use it like

```ts
@Component()
export class HomeComponent {
  public constructor(@Inject(CommonTestService) private testService:any) {
    let s1 = testService(); // new instance
    let s2 = testService(); // new instance
    ..
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi that what you say is how I am do in the first test.

And I am write there:
_I define provider of this service on the bootstrap application(for one instance on the all application)_

**But I need get instance of my service instance in static class, with only static method** not in the constructor.

For example need Inject my testService into class without constructor, how I can do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I don't see that in your code.

Comment: I am added sample on the first post: **MyStaticService**