# Angular2 - Retrieving already cached instances from the root/app injector

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

Is there a reliable way to retrieve already created instances from the root injector?  My use case is that I need to instantiate a type myself (with the `new` construct) but when setting up said type I need to grab two Angular2 Injector-managed instances.

```
app:  ApplicatinRef;
```

Where the above `app` variable is retrieved via DI itself.

```
const rootInjector: Injector = app.injector;
rootInjector.get(SomeInstance);
```

When I use the above code the `SomeInstance` type will be instantiated a second time and I was expecting it to retrieve the same instance created during bootstrapping.

Do note, however, when I call

```
rootInjector.get(SomeInstance);
```

multiple times after initially calling it, it will not instantiate it again.  So it only instantiates twice:  during bootstrapping process and when calling upon the injector itself the first time.

There are no other providers for `SomeInstance` in the DI hierarchy, only specified at application level when bootstrapping.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to get the injector at this way, angular already inject the injector. If you don't provide in any other place the instance will be the same to all components in the hierarchy. Also you don't need to use the injector directly you could ask for the instance of your service in the constructor, like this:

```
...
constructor(private serviceInstance : ServiceClassName){
    this.serviceInstance.doSomething();
}
```

If you provide in your main component, this instance will be the same in all components:

```
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
...
bootstrap(..., provide(ServiceClassName, {useClass : ServiceClassName}));
```

But you could add this instance in any place of your hierarchy using the providers configuration paramater:

```
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
...
@Component({
...
providers : [provide(ServiceClassName, {useClass : ServiceClassName})]
})
```

Providing like this will create an instance just for this component and his sub-components.

Comment: I understand it like that, but in there lies my problem.  I am dealing with an instance that I absolutely NOT want to hand over to the DI Container to handle the instance.  I need to create it myself (need full control), but inside the instance I control I need 2 instances of other types which are managed by the Angular2 Injector.  So when I instantiate the type, I want to grab those other 2 instances from the injector.  I have already implemented a workaround, but I was hoping for something more clean where I could interrogate the Angular2 API directly and not implement my own hack.

Comment: Hum..
I don't know how exactly your code works, but you can also use the DI with a factory. Inside the function you could use your injector to get angular instances and create your custom instance by yourself.
Something like this:
bootstrap(..., provide(ServiceClassName, {useFactory:  () => {
/*injector and  special logic*/
return new ServiceClassName(injectorInstance1, injectorInstance2, specialInstance);
}}));

Comment: That is perhaps something I can experiment with. Will add more detail to my question of how my code works.  Is basically a `User` domain object (of which instances will never come from DI) that I need to construct with `ListContainer`s and it's these containers that need instances from the DI system.

Comment: Why don't you use a service to provide this special instances? At this way your values can change but your interface continues the same.

Comment: For now I factored things out to a factory so instead of creating the `User` domain instances directly, I hand this over to a factory which will also setup the above-mentioned `ListContainer`s accordingly.  However, I am still not doing this via Angular2's DI system.

Comment: It depends how you will change this instances. There's another way to provide a service as multivalued but unfortunatelly I don't know how to use. It's called Multi providers. You could find more details here: [Multi Providers](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular2/2015/11/23/multi-providers-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: I posted an answer that shows how to inject a factory in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36223008/217408 (2nd example with dependency)

Comment: Thanks for comments.  A bit more info:  currently I invoke the `UserFactory.create('username')` from two services (who themselves are injected).  I will refactor things a bit that I will add another argument there which will be the factory obtained from DI for the `ListContainer`s and see how that works out.  I still want to leave the `new User(...)` part up to myself and not handing that over to DI.